# Unable to print back entered text in x86 assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I have an Assembly program here which is supposed to print a string, allow the user the enter some text, print that exact same text again and then wait for a keypress to terminate the program, using only Win32 native functions.
The problem is that everything seems to work, except printing the user entered string. It just prints a blank new line.
Here's the code:

```
global _main

extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ReadFile@20
extern _ExitProcess@4

section .text

_main:
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12

    push -11
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    push dword [ebp - 12]
    lea ecx, [_msg_end - _msg]
    push ecx
    lea edx, [_msg]
    push edx
    push ebx
    call _WriteFile@20

    push -10
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    lea ecx, [ebp - 8]
    push ecx
    push 20
    lea edx, [ebp - 4]
    push edx
    push ebx
    call _ReadFile@20

    push -11
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    push dword [ebp - 12]
    lea ecx, [ebp - 8]
    push ecx
    lea edx, [ebp - 4]
    push edx
    push ebx
    call _WriteFile@20

    push -10
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    lea ecx, [ebp - 8]
    push ecx
    push 1
    lea edx, [ebp - 4]
    push edx
    push ebx
    call _ReadFile@20

    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
_msg:
    db "Hello, world!", 10
_msg_end:
```

**EDIT** - Here's the working code:

```
global _main

extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _ReadFile@20
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ExitProcess@4

section .bss
_input_buf: resb 20

section .text
_main:
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8

    push -10
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    lea ecx, [ebp - 4]
    push ecx
    push 20
    lea eax, [_input_buf]
    push eax
    push ebx
    call _ReadFile@20

    push -11
    call _GetStdHandle@4
    mov ebx, eax

    push 0
    lea ecx, [ebp - 8]
    push ecx
    mov edx, [ebp - 4]
    push edx
    lea eax, [_input_buf]
    push eax
    push ebx
    call _WriteFile@20

    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

Comment: How could it work?  You are not reserving any space for the buffer.

Comment: Yes I am... let's say I push 8 onto the stack instead of ecx after reading the maximum 20 characters long string, and I run the program and I type 'Benjamin'. Then it will output "Benjamin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

You're only allocating 4 bytes - making space for two characters - as you are reading input into the last allocated dword on the stack:

```
ebp-12 [undefined]
ebp-8: [input length]
ebp-4: [input buffer]
ebp:
```

You're giving the length of the input string as a pointer instead of dereferencing it, making it try to output a huge number of bytes, and failing:

```
lea ecx, [ebp - 8]
push ecx <- address, not value
```